# How to build opencv from source in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: compiling, opencv

After watching a video online and writing down each code to build opencv from source everything went as bad as the word bad. 
Everything went well with building opencv. The problem was I realized it hasn't been built in the site packages of my anaconda3 folder, but rather both opencv and opencv_contrib were built in my home Directory.

I tried to copy both folders into the site packages folder, but still it didn't well. I need your help
Please any help is welcomed

Comment: Did you follow [OpenCV Official documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)? Maybe you didn`t installed with sudo, so it was installed in $HOME folder.

Comment: No I followed a different source. I did install with sudo. Is there a way to get the folders into the site packages for it to work

Comment: Could you post this video link? I cannot understand what does mean "build packages". Usually, any framework follow a  `.cfg`, containing definitions to guide its behavior and working. Look for it.